# TensorFlow custom estimator stuck when calling evaluate after training

Tags: python, tensorflow

I made a custom estimator (see this [colab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/10VKcE1sZh8F2-HYASxx7OgV8Mf4DQKFy)) in TensorFlow (v1.10) based on their [guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/custom_estimators).

I trained the toy model with:

```
tf.estimator.train_and_evaluate(est, train_spec, eval_spec)
```

and then, with some test set data, try to evaluate the model with:

```
test_fn = lambda: input_fn(DATASET['test'], run_params)
test_res = est.evaluate(input_fn=test_fn)
```

(where the `train_fn` and `valid_fn` are functionally identical to `test_fn`, e.g. sufficient for `tf.estimator.train_and_evaluate` to work).

I would expect something to happen, however this is what I get:

```
INFO:tensorflow:Calling model_fn.
INFO:tensorflow:Done calling model_fn.
INFO:tensorflow:Starting evaluation at 2018-11-09-13:38:44
INFO:tensorflow:Graph was finalized.
INFO:tensorflow:Restoring parameters from ./test/model.ckpt-100
INFO:tensorflow:Running local_init_op.
INFO:tensorflow:Done running local_init_op.
```

and then it just runs forever.

How come?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is because you repeat the dataset indefinitely:

```
# In input_fn
dataset = dataset.repeat().batch(batch_size)
```

By default, estimator.evaluate() runs until the input_fn raises an end-of-input exception. Because you repeat the test dataset indefinitely, it never raises the exception and keeps running.

You can either remove the repeat when testing, or run the evaluation for a given number of steps using the 'steps' argument as it is used in your original 'eval_spec'.

Comment: Removing the repeat works and I think I understand why steps is required when using `repeat`. I have updated the colab and tried your other suggestion, removing repeat, but this raises an error. Could you please assist?

Comment: It's because of this "labels.set_shape(O_SHAPE(params['batch_size']))". Just remove it. labels can have a different size since the number of inputs might not be dividable by batch_size meaning that the last batch might be have less data.

Comment: Removing `"labels.set_shape(O_SHAPE(params['batch_size']))` doesn't fix the issue and raises an error... >`InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Inputs to operation loss_fn/logistic_loss/Select of type Select must have the same size and shape.  Input 0: [10,20,4] != input 1: [1,20,4]` ...

Comment: change inet.set_shape(I_SHAPE(params['batch_size'])) to inet.set_shape(I_SHAPE(None)) for the same reason.

Comment: Tried that as well prior to posting my comment, this causes a similar error. One has to set the shape because tf records are the worse

Comment: It works on my side using your colab. Are you sure you changed the one inside your build_fn ?

Comment: Foremost I want to state my gratitude for you extensive assistance, if you I updated the `run_params` to have `"batch_size": None` but this raises `ValueError: None values not supported.` before the model can even get off the ground

Comment: any ideas on how to get around this?

Comment: could you maybe look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53307954/tensorflow-custom-estimator-predict-throwing-value-error